# How is the channel selected in select if there is a timer?

Tags: go, channel

I am trying to understand how select and timer work. I have a simple example

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan int, 10)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        ch1 <- i
    }
    timer := time.NewTimer(1 * time.Second)
    close(ch1)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        select {
        case data, ok := <-ch1:              //1
            if !ok {
                fmt.Println("Data channel close", data)
                return
            }
            fmt.Println("Not close", data)
        case <-timer.C:                      //2
            fmt.Println("Timer triggered")
            timer.Reset(1 * time.Second)
        }
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }

}
```

[play](https://go.dev/play/p/A6HFZ-2i8IF)

I expected that because there is data in the ch1 channel, it will always work //1. But it happens that only //2 works

```
Not close 0
Timer triggered
Timer triggered
Timer triggered
Timer triggered
Timer triggered
Timer triggered
Not close 1
Not close 2
Timer triggered

Program exited.
```

How to understand which case will work?

Comment: A select blocks until one of its cases can run, then it executes that case. It chooses one at **random** if multiple are ready.

Comment: There isn't a predictable behavior for your program. When two possible executions can happen or ready, `select` chooses one randomly - https://go.dev/ref/spec#Select_statements